# How to cover .addError method in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Full Trigger for Test is below.  I am getting 80% coverage with my test class.

```
trigger PreventIncidentDelete on Incident__c (before delete) {
    String profileName=[SELECT id,Name FROM Profile WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getProfileId()].Name ;

    if(System.Trigger.IsDelete)  { 

        for (Incident__c Incd : trigger.old)  {

            if (profileName != 'System Administrator' )  { 
                Incd.addError('Insufficient privilege, please do not delete this record.');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Below is my test class.

```
@isTest
public class testPreventIncidentDeletion {

    static testmethod void testPreventIncDel(){       

        Incident__c incd = new Incident__c();   
        incd.FKClient__c =  '005F0000003abcdeAA';
        incd.FKAccount__c = '001F000001OabcdeAR';
        incd.Office_Location__c = 'New York';
        incd.Client_Project__c = 'IT - Applications';
        incd.FKCategory__c = 'a1DF000000abcdeAK';
        incd.incidentDescription__c = 'Testing prevent Incident records deletion.';
        insert incd;


        Profile p = [SELECT Id from Profile WHERE Name ='ServiceDesk Staff'];
        User u1 = new User();
        u1.Alias = 'Test1S';
        u1.Country = 'United States';
        u1.LastName='Smith';
        u1.FirstName='Test1';
        u1.email='test1.user@example.com';
        u1.emailencodingkey='UTF-8';
        u1.languagelocalekey='en_US';
        u1.localesidkey='en_US';
        u1.ProfileId=p.Id;
        u1.UserRoleId='00EF00000016cZ1MAI';           
        u1.timezonesidkey='America/Chicago';
        u1.username='123456@example.com';
        u1.CommunityNickname='123456@example.com';
        insert u1;

        System.runAs(u1) {

            test.startTest();        

            try{   
                delete incd;
                system.assert(false, 'An error was exptected');
            }

            catch(Exception e){            

                system.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Insufficient privilege, please do not delete this record.'));    
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't tell under what conditions you add that error until you give us more of the trigger context. As written this question is impossible to answer other than to tell you that you need to hit the proper execution path, which is all you ever have to do to achieve code coverage.

Comment: Additionally, you will need an assert after `delete incd` like `system.assert(false,'An Error Was Expected')` so that if it does not error as expected your test will fail

Comment: I have edited it with the full trigger code.

Comment: I edited my test class and now is 0% coverage, please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: In addition to this you may want to consider either making the OWD public Read Only if public or removing the "Delete" permission from all profiles except system admin. This would prevent the ability to even see the delete option

Comment: @Qdu - Simply adding the assert will not cause 0% coverage in a passing test method.

Comment: IT Staff profile need to have modify all permission to be able to approve Incident records to spawn Change Request and Tasks. But we do not want staff to delete records unless user is System Administrator.  I have added an IT Staff user info into the test and System.runAs(u1).  But it made it worse.

Comment: @Qdu - You can give that profile those permissions while everyone else does not have delete permissions. Just FYI. Not sure a trigger is need for this but it depends on your overall security requirements

Comment: Be careful with checking for the name of a standard profile, as they get translated. If you run this code as a System Administrator with a different language, you will also get the error.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment to your post, you should add an assert statement after the `delete` command, to make sure that the test will fail if the exception is not thrown by the code, which I believe is happening your case thus not getting more code coverage.

You can user the `System.runAs(User u)` utility in your test to run with a User from a profile which is not allowed in your trigger logic. See documentation in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm

In your test you could create a new user with a different profile (such as Standard User profile), which is not allowed to delete records in your trigger logic, and put that `delete` statement in the runAs context, to make sure the Exception will be thrown.

Comment: I modified my code (see above) and now getting 0% coverage, please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: Your test is passing? Or failing with which message?

Comment: I don't know how other CRUD permissions are set in your org for those objects' access. Have in mind that you are creating the Incident__c object with the test default user (System Administrator) and then trying to delete it with the user you created, which may not have access to it. You could try to both create and delete that object inside the runAs context (leave only the profile and user part outside the runAs context, move object creation and deletion and asserts inside the context). Tell me if the test passes or fails and code coverage after that.

Comment: @MauricioOliveira - thats the point of the test. OP does not want that user to be able to delete and thus it should throw an error.

Comment: I am able to test 100% now.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Qdu, glad to hear you managed to solve it. And Eric, thanks for pointing out, my text is indeed a bit misleading. What I meant to say is that he could be facing permission/access to the object because it was created by the Admin and the other profile couldn't even "see" it, so the trigger was not even being fired for the delete operation. Before testing the trigger behavior, he should make sure in the test he has access to the object. Anyway, it seems he already got it working ;)